# How to make Kaa log upload event based instead of time based

Tags: kaa

I've only recently started to work with KaaIoT and I am wondering if there is another way to store a log bucked to the server.

```
/* some headers */

static void main_callback(void *context)
{
    kaa_user_log_record_t *log_record = kaa_logging_time_collection_create();
    log_record->test_time = kaa_string_copy_create("some_time");
    kaa_logging_add_record(kaa_client_get_context(context)->log_collector, log_record, NULL);
}

/* some other configuration */

error = kaa_client_start(kaa_client, main_callback, kaa_client, 5);
```

When I execute this code, the string "some_time" will be stored to the server every 5 seconds.
I was wondering if there was an other way to do this, like upload the log to the server when I press my 'enter' key? But I can't seem to find a command for this.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding kaa_logging_add_record, just add the record to the storing bucket waiting to be sent according to the logging strategy you have defined. (https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/autogen-docs/client-c/v0.10.0/kaa__logging_8h.html#af0fadc09a50f5e38603271a08c581417) . The parameter 5 sec in kaa_client_start is only a delay to cycle the call back function. If you want to register an event, first you have to store it in the log bucket and the timestamp if you want to record at what time happened. If you want to notify at the moment, the I think you should use Notifications or Events. I am also scratching my head in something similar and I wonder if there is a better way.